# Taskbar and desktop refreshing

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, desktop, display-driver

I have an issue that my HP 650 laptop is doing refreshing of taskbar and desktop in every 2 minutes.

When refreshing the icons from the taskbar are disappearing for 1-2 second and then again shown.

What can be the reason of this problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest updating the display driver for your laptop but it could be malware as well.  I can suggest malware removal tools but try the display driver(s) first.

Comment: Hi, 
I just did the display driver update but anyways it continues refreshing. Can you suggest which malware tools to use?

Comment: Install all Microsoft Updates although I'm sure you would have, I use these ones:
http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/stinger.aspx
https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/
http://www.vipreantivirus.com/live/

Comment: You don't have a second screen connected by any chance?  Worth disconnecting that if you do, perhaps disconnect all peripherals for a bit to confirm it isn't being caused by an external device

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, run this from an elevated command prompt to correct any system file corruptions - Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Comment: I tried malwareBytes , but as it says no malware is detected

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by (surprisingly) Norton AntiVirus installed on the machine by the factory image!

If you:

1. Start your Windows 8 computer but DON'T click to go to "Desktop" view
2. Immediately start typing "Programs and features"
3. Open "Programs and features" - so you can see your list of installed programs
4. Uninstall anything "Norton" related
5. Complete the uninstall by rebooting your computer
6. Live a hassle-free life with Windows 8.

Comment: Hi, nothing was found related to norton