# Windows 10 refreshes continuously

Tags: windows-10, refresh

I have an HP Envy dv7 laptop and I updated my windows from 8.1 to 10. The problem is that desktop icons are refreshing every second and I don't why. I searched for a solution but nothing was related to windows 10 specifically so I tried what is suggested in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/775987/taskbar-and-desktop-refreshing) but it didn't work.

So what is going wrong in my computer and what's the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem on Asus laptop after I did clean install. You have two options:

Do clean install(in my case I would have to do it again):
http://www.theverge.com/2015/7/31/9077997/microsoft-windows-10-clean-install-how-to-guide

Or you can use System Restore or Recovery. In one of the two there was option to remove all installed apps and only keep personal files. That helped my case!

Answer (score 2):

Control panel / Internet Options / Advanced / Reset IE settings to default

Then click RESET and the improvement is immediate. I have restarted twice & even got the audio back.

Comment: hope this works for others, I had to reinstall the whole thing. I had many problems concerning the battery and heat but they disappeared when I reinstalled windows. still don't know why it didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's explorer, or one of the components loaded/working with explorer.
Kill explorer.exe (all instances) if possible using Task Manager, then restart explorer (also from TM). This worked for me.

Seems usually triggered by processes with high activity; not sure if is related to the search indexer (I suspect this one since processes accessing the disk on a high rate are probably caught by windows search and keeps refreshing). Looks like a W10 bug.

For me this was triggered by a VirtualBox installation of a Windows 10; as soon as I started install, desktop and taskbar flashed every second. Kill/restart explorer solved the issue for me.

Comment: I read more about this problem and what I found was that for an HP laptop the problem is caused by the simplePass driver. I terminated its processes and disabled it to run on startup and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

After a day trying and searching the internet i found the solution, at least for me, Remove/uninstall IDP audio. Lots of people don;t even know they have it

Comment: This problem was common mainly on HP laptops because of an error in the HP simplepass driver. I disabled it and everything is fine now.